# How to Group consecutive dates together which are separated by hour in Dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have the following input data and I am trying to group consecutive DateTime together that increments by hr. version used: Dataweave 2.3, Mule 4.3

```
Input data.
["2020-03-03T06:00:00", "2020-03-03T07:00:00", "2020-03-03T08:00:00", 
"2020-03-03T09:00:00", "2020-03-03T13:00:00", "2020-03-03T14:00:00", 
"2020-03-03T15:00:00", "2020-03-04T06:00:00", "2020-03-04T07:00:00", 
"2020-03-04T08:00:00", "2020-03-04T09:00:00"]
```

Business Logic:
From the above input some of the data are consecutive by hour. Index (0,1,2,3) and (4,5,6) and (7,8,9,10) are grouped by an hour. Aim is to merge these consecutive dates together and create object set as below with fromDate being lowest Date of the group and toDate being highest date of the group. Hope I am clear with requirement.

```
Expected Output.
[{"fromDate" : "2020-03-03T06:00:00", "toDate" : "2020-03-03T09:00:00" },
 {"fromDate" : "2020-03-03T13:00:00", "toDate" : "2020-03-03T15:00:00" },
 {"fromDate" : "2020-03-04T06:00:00", "toDate" : "2020-03-04T09:00:00" }]
```

I have tried map, groupby, reduce but couldn't figure this out. Please help.

Comment: Whats the business logic to generate the output ? The input has 11 entries, while the output has 6, is something getting filtered out ? There is no clear relationship between the fromDate and toDate either.

Answer (score 5):

Very interesting challenge. In order to do this I've implemented a function called clusterBy that groups consecutive elements that matches a given criteria. Once I have that I only needed to map the first and last of each cluster into the object. See the code below

```
%dw 2.0 
fun clusterWhile<T>(elements: Array<T>,  criteria: (source:T, target:T) -> Boolean) = do {
    fun clusterLoop(elements, value, carrier, criteria) = 
        elements  match {
            case [] ->  carrier
            case [x ~ xs] ->  
                if(criteria(value, x)) do {
                    var updatedCarrier = carrier update {
                        case [-1] -> $ << x    
                    }
                    ---
                    clusterLoop(xs, x, updatedCarrier, criteria)
                }
            else 
                clusterLoop(xs, x, carrier << [x], criteria)
    }

    ---
    elements match {
        case [] -> []
        case [x ~ xs] -> clusterLoop(xs, x, [[x]], criteria)
    }
}    


---
payload 
    clusterWhile ((source, target) -> target as DateTime - source as DateTime == |PT1H|)
    map ((item, index) -> {
        fromDate: item[0],
        toDate: item[-1]
})
```

Comment: That's brilliant. I would suggest that the condition may need to be reviewed for time differences that are not exactly 1 hour. For example what happens if the difference is 1:15:00 or 0:35:00? Maybe the condition should be `<=|PT1H|` but that's a business definition and doesn't affect the answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv headerLineNumber = 0 , header = true
//Below dtList results in Input Payload.
var dtList = flatten(payload.payload) map ($."updated-at" as DateTime as String {format: "u-LL-d'T'HH:00:00'Z'"}) orderBy ($) distinctBy ($)
var fromDt =  dtList map ((item, index) -> if((item - |PT1H|) as String != (dtList[index-1])) item else "") 
var toDt = fromDt map ((item, index) ->  if(dtList[index] == item ) dtList[index-1] else "" ) filter ($ != "") orderBy ($)
---
fromDt filter ($ != "") map ((item, index) -> {fromDate: item} ++ {toDate:  (toDt[index] + |PT1H|) })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).